# Webserver for API

Tags: javascript, ruby, api, node.js, webserver

Which webserver would you recommend to receive UDP post requests? I would like to build a simple web API to receive post requests in JSON format and I would like to store them in a Redis database.

Would you go for Node.js? I was hoping to find a simple Ruby alternative.

Comment: I know this doesnt help much, but TCP is probably better if your sending anything via JSON, cause UDP wont check if the request completed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Thin is the most secure and extensible ruby web server. It combines together ruby libraries mongrel parser, event machine and rack. Just do

```
sudo gem install thin
```

or `gem install thin` if you are using rvm.

In the console, go to your app directory and run.

```
thin start
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple in Ruby means Sinatra.
Node.js could be the answer too, depends on what you're more familiar with.

Comment: I'm more looking for a fast/suitable webserver and not a framework. What about Thin, Reel, Ricer or Goliath compared to Node.js? Any experiences?

Comment: Oh ok, didn't understand the question right away... In that case I'd suggest you to use thin or roll your own with Node.js (which is super easy too).
Node.js by my experience, performs best and is lighter. But it depends on your needs.